# Laravel l5-swagger api-docs.json file not found

Tags: php, json, laravel, swagger

I am installed

```
composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger:5.6.*",
```

and i have a api-docs.json from a swagger that I added to storage/api-docs/api-docs.json.
But when i go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/documentation
```

I got error

```
Fetch error Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/api-docs.json
```

I tried to run

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

but it logically returns an error

```
Required @OA\Info() not found
```

because it wants me to manually enter all the api information in the classes, but my api is quite large so it will take me a long time to rewrite it.

Can `darkaonline/l5-swagger` just read my api-docs.json file from the storage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Info` as mentioned in the error.

A simple, yet powerful solution would be adding it to `App\Http\Controller::class`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;



#[OA\Info(title: "My First API", version: "0.1",)]

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

This will ensure that the `Info` is added to all your requests as well.

You can then easily add your PathItems, as en example for `App\Http\Controller\Api\HeartbeatController::class`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

class HeartbeatController extends Controller
{
    #[OA\Get(
        path: '/heartbeat',
        responses: [
            new OA\Response(response: '200', description: 'API is running', content: new OA\JsonContent(example: ['status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'API is running']))
        ],
    )]
    public function __invoke(): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'message' => 'API is running',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it returns error Required @OA\PathItem() not found.  So he's still trying to get me to manually add all the annotations

Comment: The `PathItem` is basically another error. I've edited my response to reflect the context for how you can add a `PathItem`.

Comment: Еhat's the problem that I don't want to add PathItem for each class because it will take a lot of time and i want just use already created api-docs.json

Comment: That's not how this specific package works.